# iOS 8 size classes for iPad landscape

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard, ios8, size-classes

It seems all the current iOS devices maps to the new iOS 8 size classes nicely except iPad landscape?  I seem not able to figure out how to use the size class feature to draw a different scene for iPad landscape (different from iPad portrait)?

Is that intended by design in Apple's mind or am I miss something about the iOS size classes?

Comment: 17633678 bug id for this. I'm encountering the same thing, but I think it is by design.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm sure it's by design, but I can neither think of why, or how to actually achieve what OP needs (distinct layout for iPad landscape)

Comment: haven't seen any progress on this either. to help further clarify:  
iPhone portrait = "compact width, regular height"  
iPhone landscape = "regular width, compact height"  
iPad in portrait or landscape = " regular width, regular height"  

so there's no way to differentiate between them in storyboards using size classes.

Comment: on second pass it seems that I was misinformed on the iPhone landscape, this post http://www.learnswift.io/blog/2014/6/12/size-classes-with-xcode-6-and-swift shows iPhone landscape actually gets 'compact width, compact height' to further confuse things..

Comment: I cannot understand why the iPhone landscape has compact width as well. It makes no sense, all the logic leads to it being regular width ? Since it has regular height on portrait mode.

Comment: @thisispete in the comments of the link you have provided, there is a solution to the problem of the OP. However, I cannot understand why the same thing cannot be done the way it is done with the iPhone.

Comment: it sounds like the new iphone 6+ gets compact height, regular width in landscape, which is how it gets the dual pane layouts in mail etc.

Comment: Any solutions for this?

Comment: @thisispete iPhones in landscape: ANY width, compact height

Comment: Just ran into this issue myself. Was excited to start playing with these new storyboards that could be used for all devices only to find out at the last minute that it doesn't support differentiating between iPads in portrait or landscape :-( I hope Apple do something about this soon.

Comment: Yeah this is a massive shortfall of Apple's design and I find it incredibly disappointing.

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be Apple's intent to treat both iPad orientations as the same -- but as a number of us are finding, there are very legitimate design reasons to want to vary the UI layout for iPad Portrait vs. iPad Landscape.

However, I believe I have an answer for adapting size classes to do just what you need.

Please see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28268200/4517929

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be by design (which I think we can all agree is lame). You'll probably have to resort to doing things in code for iPad landscape layout by checking something like

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation.isLandscape
```