# Worklight and iPhone 6 / 6 plus

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, splash-screen, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

We are migrating from worklight 5.0.6.2 to worklight 6.2 (with latest ifix from fixcentral)

At the same occasion, we would like to make our hybrid app compatible with iphone 6 and 6 plus new screen sizes.
From what I've understood we need to put new splash screen size & icon size in xcode for it 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html
and
[Supporting iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ with different launch/splash screen image for iPad Portrait and Landscape orientations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886703/supporting-iphone-6-and-iphone-6-with-differant-launch-splash-screen-image-for)

But since worklight is not compatible with asset catalog yet, I don't know how to do this properly without messing the splash screen display.
Any recommandations ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sizes [are as follows](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html):

- For iPhone 6:

  - 750 x 1334 (@3x) for portrait
  - 1334 x 750 (@3x) for landscape
- For iPhone 6 Plus:

  - 1242 x 2208 (@3x) for portrait
  - 2208 x 1242 (@3x) for landscape

Name the files as follows as place them together with the rest of the images in the iphone\native\Resources folder.

- For iPhone:

  - Default@3x~iphone.png
- For iPad:

  - Default-Landscape@3x~ipad.png
  - Default-Portrait@3x~ipad.png

Comment: Hi Idan,
Thanks for the quick answer, but that didn't work.
It just keeps on using the old images (for lower resolutions)
I've then tried the following:
http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2014/09/iphone-6-and-6-plus-launch-images-for.html

Now they are taken into account but only for 1~2 seconds, then the old images for lower resolutions are displayed zoomed in for also 1~2 seconds
Isn't it because of the worklight SDK SplashImageViewController-Portrait.xib not being adapted for higher screen size yet ?

Comment: I'll get back to you about that.

Comment: @piflechien, We've identified the error. To received a fixed version, you'll need to open a PMR.

Comment: Hi Idan, thanks for the answer. Ok we'll open a PMR ;-). Cheers

Comment: @piflechien, I think you've received an iFix by now. If my answer helped you, please mark it as Answered.

Comment: Hi Idan, yes we received a fix last week: APAR PI26896