# Still not optimized for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I have an app that just went live and it's still not saying "Optimized for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus"

- I added launch screens and app icons in required resolutions.
- Adjusted all inner screen to fit with the new iPhone screens.
- Added screenshots for 4.7 and 5.5 inches devices on iTunes Connect.

What am I missing now?

Comment: you compiled with sdk8 ?

Comment: yes, deployed from Xcode 6.0.1

Comment: do you have 64bit architecture? -- or rather what are your architectures and valid architectures settings like

Comment: yes, arm64 was included.

Comment: I've just resubmitted the app. Will answer to my question for positive outcome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After few additional adjustments made, I had re-submitted the app few days ago. Now it's live and optimized for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus!

Here are the steps I made:

- Added [App icon](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) (including Settings Icon and Spotlight Icon) & [Launch images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1) to `Images.xcassets` in proper resolution and naming of the files (self-explanatory as they are) was done as following:

[image][image]

- Additionally added `Launch Screen` file. Because [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1) it's important to add.
  [image]
- Made sure that App icon, Launch Image and Launch file sources were properly selected at `Project Targets -> General`
  [image]
- Adjusted all inner screens to fit with the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus screens, of course!
- Made sure that `arm64` was included in `Project Targets -> Build Settings`. (Bye bye iOS 5 support!)
  [image]
- Removed `armv7` from `Required device capabilities` (a.k.a. [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html)) in `info.plist`
  [image]
- On iTunes Connect, added screenshots for 4.7 and 5.5 inches devices **excluding the device status bar**. [[Screenshot Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2)]

Comment: Hello @Asif, is it really necessary to have the Launch Screen file to make the app optimised for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus?

Comment: @TiagoPereira yes, apparently Apple tagged it as "important". https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1

Comment: Is removing `armv7` actually necessary? That seems bizarre.

Comment: Hi @AsifAsif, How did you optimize your existing app for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus?

Comment: the steps above I did to make an existing iPhone 5-optimized app again optimizing for iPhone 6 and 6+.

Answer (score 1):

Launch screen file should also be selected on your target settings:

[image]

Comment: been there, no difference.

Comment: He said he added the launch screens so this answer is more like a comment in the form 'have you done it right' ;)

Comment: as a matter of fact, launch screen isn't really required when you have the launch images properly in place. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25982710/1336105

Comment: @AsifAsif, you should edit your answer above to say so