# iPhone6,6+ are not shown in compatibility section on the App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store

I submitted an app to the App Store one week ago.

I had tested it on the iPhone6 and 6+ simulators and it was OK.

Now it is [available on the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/heapo-copy-paste-sync-clipboard/id921961118?ls=1&mt=8) but in the compatibility section iPhone6 and iPhone6+ are not shown.
Why? Is it because of building with xCode 6.0?

More information about my build config:

```
XCode 6.0
Deployment-Target: 7.0
Valid Architectures: arm64, armv7, armv7s, arm6
```

Comment: Did you include the launch images for iPhone 6 and 6+ resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issues. Did few adjustments to get iPhone 6 and 6+ compatibility. You may refer to the steps I took: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26503186/1336105

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand the step no6. Should I remove armv7 from plist file?

Comment: including `armv7` under `Required Device Capabilities` means that the app will be compiled **only for the armv7 instruction set**, where as iPhone 6 and 6+ are optimized for arm64 instruction set (although these devices are backward compatible with armv7 architecture). So removing it from plist is a safe bet.