# Optimize app for iPhone 6 / iPhone 6 plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I have doubts that guidelines are recommended to adapt an app to the new screens of iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus (I've added all new icons and splash screen: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) . I know that for iPhone 6 plus images are @3x and the width of the iPhone 6 is larger than previous versions.

My question is, for example, if the font sizes are recommended to be different, smaller or if xcode does this automatically. The same with the size of images.

I have read the Apple guidelines but does have not clarified my question:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH66-SW1

Any recommendation, guideline or advice?

**UPDATE:** I found a possible solution. If you use a Launch xib (or storyboard), the screens are adapt to new devices. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26252320/still-not-optimized-for-iphone-6-and-iphone-6-plus).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should think of the iPhone/iPad screen in *points* rather than *pixels*. Doing so means that iOS does the "right thing" (or at least what Apple thinks is the right thing) on each device. In general, the font size remains the same on all devices. On iPhone6/6+ you just get more information on-screen.

Comment: @StephenDarlington But font size 22 (in point) in iPhone 6 is still bigger when presented in iPhone 5

Comment: Font size 22 is different on an iPad and iPad mini. You _can_ detect the screen size of the 6+ and do different things, but you shouldn't.

Comment: @onmyway133 no its not. You need to enable full resolution for 6 and 6 plus by adding launch images