# Enable "Optimized iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus" text message compatibility description on apple store

Tags: ios, app-store

My app doesn't show the "Optimized for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus" message on the App Store. My app works fine on both devices. I have used a launch screen file with xib, launch images and added app icon support for 3x scale. But it's not working. Can anybody tell me how to enable this label?

Comment: Isn't it that you should be selecting this information when you were uploading the App?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26252320/1402846