# Force iOS app to run in iPhone mode on iPad with Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, autolayout

My iOS application has just been rejected for the following reason:

> iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

I use Autolayout to size for all 4 device resolutions. Unfortunately, this means the app scales on iPad instead of running in iPhone mode. Is there an easy fix for this without hard coding each of my views for iPad?

The app is set to iPhone-only in the app's project settings.

Images

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXGJF.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH1tx.jpg

Comment: Is your app meant to be universal or just iPhone only? If iPhone only when you run your app it should look exactly like it does on an iPhone whether autolayout is enabled or not so it shouldn't fill the entire view of the iPad. An example of how it should work is http://www.simonblog.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/iPhone-App-in-iPad.jpg

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. You have not provided images of how the application looks on iPad devices and what the exact problem is. Perhaps your UI is tailored for 4" displayes, and some elements are cut off at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks. I've attached pictures. I want the iPad to run the iPhone app as shown in Popeye's screenshot. The device family is set to iPhone in Xcode 6. Any ideas?

Comment: Very interesting... so you are definitely iphone-only on the project settings, not universal? Wow, I just tried it and I'm seeing the same behavior! This looks like yet another xcode/ios bug to me, and they denied you for it!

Comment: Sounds like you have a pretty solid case for appealing the rejection.

Comment: Are you using a Launch screen nib file? That's how I've enabled support for the 6 and 6+ in my own dev, but *supposedly* you can just use launch images to the same effect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886703/supporting-iphone-6-and-iphone-6-with-different-launch-splash-screen-image-for maybe that would work?

Comment: Thanks Shawn, that did work. It seems to show correctly as an iPhone app (3.5 inch scaled version?) in the iPad simulator.

It's such a shame that using the .xib fools it somehow. I hope I can get expedited review. 

http://imgur.com/ToWL0mw

Comment: Actually, now it doesn't show in the correct resolution of iPhone 6/6+.