# Xcode 6.1.1 Launch Images for Universal build

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, image, launch

Faced the problem with Launch images in Xcode 6.1.1
When I set all of the images - iPhone 4s, iPhone 5/5s and iPhone 6 doesn't show up (black screen), however the resolutions for the particular device is set right, as all of the images are on their places.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71223199/temp/01.png

I use Landscape right/left.

Funny stuff is when I'm adding them one by one, they first work.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71223199/temp/02.png

But once I add images for iPhone 6/6+ they don't work again.
iPad works fine.

Have anyone seen any step-by-step tutorial on how to set up images?
I have my another project (portrait orientation) and it works fine when images for all devices are set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like Apple didn't fix this landscape-only launch images bug with their latest update to Xcode.  You'll likely have to manually edit your project's info.plist file to include the UILaunchImages array.  The selected answer here worked for me for the previous version of Xcode:

[How do I create launch images for iPhone 6 / 6 Plus Landscape Only Apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25926661/how-do-i-create-launch-images-for-iphone-6-6-plus-landscape-only-apps)

More detail on why this particular bug exists (at least it did in Xcode 6.1) in the last post of this thread:

[Supporting iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ with different launch/splash screen image for iPad Portrait and Landscape orientations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886703/supporting-iphone-6-and-iphone-6-with-different-launch-splash-screen-image-for)