# iOS Replace the default Keyboard with a shorter Keyboard

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8.1, ios8-extension

How can I get the default keyboard to be shorter like the keyboard on the right?
The standard keyboard is the left, how do I get it to have the height of the one on the right?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left keyboard is not taller than the right keyboard— they are the same height, in points.  The difference is in the scale of the screen; i.e. the pixels are smaller on the right.  Assuming that these are the same device, the difference is caused by one of two things:

- The app on the left is not updated to support the higher resolution screens of the iPhone 6 and 6+.  To remedy this, you can either specify a .xib as your "Launch Screen File" in the target's General settings, or add a launch image for iPhone 6 and 6+ to your asset catalog.
- The app on the left is running on a device which is in "Zoomed" view mode.  To change this, follow this path in your Settings app: General > Display & Brightness > View.

**Edit**: A good tip for recognizing such resolution differences (on an iPhone 6 or 6+) is to watch the clock as an app launches.  If it gets bigger, then your device is set to the "Standard" view mode, and the application has not been updated to support iPhone 6/6+ resolutions.  If the clock stays the same size, then either the app has been updated to support iPhone 6, or the device is in the "Zoomed" view mode (or both).

Comment: The app on the left may also not be running on an iPhone 6.

Comment: Agreed.  My answer totally makes the assumption that it's the same device.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control the height of the keyboard. The keyboard on the left is looks taller because this app hasn't been updated for iPhone 6/6+ screens, so the keyboard and everything else in the app has been stretched.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886703/supporting-iphone-6-and-iphone-6-with-different-launch-splash-screen-image-for) for how to support the new 6 screen sizes.