# How to use a single launch screen file in Xcode for all iOS 8 devices?

Tags: xcode, ios8, uiimageview, jpeg, distortion

I have a single Launch Screen File (a NIB with a UIImageView and a JPEG) in Xcode 6 as launch image for all iPhone and iPad devices that run iOS 8 in Landscape mode. I set the size of the UIImageView to 5.5 in. The launch screen works well for the iPhone 5 and 6, but it looks distorted for the iPhone 4 and iPad. How can I fix this so that one Launch Screen File works for all devices that support iOS 8? I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25926661/how-do-i-create-launch-images-for-iphone-6-6-plus-landscape-only-apps) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886703/supporting-iphone-6-and-iphone-6-with-different-launch-splash-screen-image-for/26275887#26275887) already, I don't want to use the plist, there has to be a way to set the NIB correctly for all devices with a single JPEG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2014/08/working-with-size-classes-in-interface-builder/). I switched to a storyboard and set that as the launch image. I set the size classes to ensure my launch image works on all devices that support iOS 8. In particular the Assistant Editor lets you see what happens as your work with constraints. For iOS 7 I left the image sets since I had those setup already. Works great for both now!

Comment: Wayback Machine to the rescue: 

https://web.archive.org/web/20150911231224/http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2014/08/working-with-size-classes-in-interface-builder/