# Xcode Launch Image for iPhone 6 landscape...?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

My app is landscape only, and I'm trying to add launch images, but I don't see anywhere in the Launch Image assets a placeholder to drag the image for "Retina HD 4.7" Landscape.

Please advise.

[image]

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25960203/2242157

Comment: But what's the reason for there not being a spot in the screen shot I posted for iPhone 6 landscape?

Comment: Actually I don't know. I searched a little online and only answer I got is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26275887/2242157

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on one of my apps that I started developing and then a xcode update came along. I had to delete the file and create a new one, then all of the choices were there. Give that a shot. Always backup first.